# AMD-compliant JavaScript - any difference between defining then returning vs just returning

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I would like to know if there is any difference between the following

```
define(
    function () {
        var Dog = {
             Bark: function () { alert('Woof! Woof! Woof!'); }
        };
    return Dog;
});
```

and

```
define(
    function () {
        return {
             Bark: function () { alert('Woof! Woof! Woof!'); }
        };
});
```

and

```
define(
    function () {
        function Dog()  {
             this.Bark = function () { alert('Woof! Woof! Woof!'); };
        };
    return Dog;
});
```

I think I prefer the first in terms of how it looks, but I am worried that it is different from the second and third in that it will be evaluated before being returned... I realize that is kind of a silly statement since obviously all function declarations need to be evaluated at some point, but not knowing how JavaScript works under the hood, I would appreciate clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and the second are almost the same. The real difference can be noticed in the third option. In that case you are returning a function which is likely to be called with the *new* operator. Nevertheless that third option have some faults making it the worst option:

Fisrt of all the *Dog* function will create a new object allocating a new *Bark* function in the memory. So in terms of memory efficiency this option is clearly worst than the other two because the other two just create one single object allocating on single *Bark* function. Back to the third case you could improve it by doing:

```
define(
    function () {
        function Dog()  {
        };

        Dog.prototype.Bark = function () { alert('Woof! Woof! Woof!'); };
    return Dog;
});
```

By doing that you can be sure that you will have only one instance of the *Bark* function that will be shared by all the objects created with the *Dog* function.

The other defect I noticed is that you are not ensuring that the *Dog* function will create an object. I mean, what will happen if it is called without the *new* operator?. It can be the cause of very nasty bugs like this one:

```
var tommy = Dog();
tommy.Bark(); //Bark is undefined because tommy is equal to Dog's return value
```

So to deal with this you could do:

```
define(
    function () {
        function Dog()  {
            if(!(this instanceof Dog)){
                return new Dog();
            }
        };

        Dog.prototype.Bark = function () { alert('Woof! Woof! Woof!'); };
    return Dog;
});
```

With this *improved* third option the choise relies on the problem you are trying to solve. Will you need more than one instance of that object? is that's the case then you should use the *improved* third option, otherwise you may use the first or second option.

Answer (score 1):

The first and second examples are practically identical, in the first you just signal to a reader what "kind" of the object is being returned by naming it using a temporary variable. One thing to notice is that this object is shared in all modules requiring this module as their dependency, thus is a kind of singleton.

The third one is quite different. You are returning a function to be used to create a new object (or more of them) in terms of `new Dog()` if `Dog` is an alias of this module in a place where this module is required as a dependency. This function is shared, but does not contain `Bark` or other methods, its instances do, but those are not shared.

You can write the third one also as

```
define(function () {
    return function Dog()  {
         this.Bark = function () { alert('Woof! Woof! Woof!'); };
    };
});
```

Where the Dog name of the function is even optional (but often recommended for readability/debugging).